# Match same amount of characters as matched by previous group

Tags: ruby, regex

Basically, I need a combination of `\k` and `\g`.

Here is an example:

I have strings in the form of `"123045 ; 67089"`. I have to match this only if there is a repeating digit in both numbers on the same position in respect to the end of the number. In this case, the `0` in `123045` is two positions away from the end of the number as is the `0` in `67089`.

---

The problem is that if I use backreferences, the entire remainders of the numbers have to match (aka `45` with `89`):

```
^\d*(\d)(\d*) ; \d*\1\2$
```

And if I use pattern reexecution, I have to give specific number of characters remaining (in this case - two):

```
^\d*(\d)(\d{2}) ; \d*\1\g<2>$
```

---

Yes, it has to be in a single regex.

Comment: Just a very quick shot, not sure if ruby supports PCRE completely and not tested fully: https://regex101.com/r/u0ZBdR/3

Comment: @SebastianProske: Ruby regex runs on Onigmo, not PCRE. It supports recursion with the help of `\g<N>` notation. Use [Rubular](http://rubular.com) to test Ruby regex patterns.

Comment: @SebastianProske, this is clever, I should have thought of something like that. Even though it doesn't handle invalid input, but that can be tweaked. Post that as an answer (just replace `(?2)` with `\g<2>`).

Comment: @ndn I have updated the regex101 link again, should handle some more edge cases and validate. I will post my answer when I am back home.

Comment: @Downvoter, could you explain?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are facing here is a balancing problem. You can use recursion to solve it, my approach would be:

```
^\d*(\d)(?:(\d(?:(\s*;\s*\d*\1)|\g<2>)\d)|\g<3>)$
```

This will take `\s*;\s*\d*\1` as the content between two balanced groups of numbers. To get out of the recursion, this content has to be matched exactly once (to avoid matches like `122` or `12;1;13`). The recursion to this content as an alternation is for the case of the doubled digit being the last of each number.

You can find some test cases [here](http://rubular.com/r/zFITnoF5qM)